# Closing a JFrame from another Method

Tags: java, methods, jframe, jpanel

This Loading window opens and I want it to close once the closeLoadingWindow method runs. I have a button that triggers the closeLoadingWindow method in another class. Any help??

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class LoadingScreen {


  public static void createLoadingWindow()
  {
   JFrame LoadingFrame = new JFrame("Loading");
   LoadingFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

   JPanel LoadingPanel = new JPanel();
   LoadingFrame.add(LoadingPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

   ImageIcon LoadingGif = new ImageIcon();
   JLabel LoadingLabel = new JLabel(LoadingGif);
   LoadingPanel.add(LoadingLabel);
   LoadingFrame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void closeLoadingWindow()
  {
     dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: you should call `dispose()` on frame.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if you initialised the Loading Frame as so:

```
public class LoadingScreen{
    JFrame LoadingFrame;
    public void createLoadingWindow(){
          LoadingFrame = new JFrame("Loading");
          ...
    }
    public void closeLoadingWindow(){
         LoadingFrame.dispose();
    }
}
```

Or you could pass the Frame Loading frame as a parameter in the close LoadingWindow() method:

```
public void closeLoadingWindow(JFrame LoadingFrame){
     LoadingFrame.dispose();
}
```